# Deleting DynamoDB with Lambda using aws-sdk causes the process to be terminated mid-process

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Here is the package used and other information.

```
"@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.370.0"
"@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.377.0"
```

A process is created to delete records in DynamoDB.

I ran it in Lambda to check and found that the deletion was not taking place.

Curious, I ran the Lambda again and found that the deletion was done.

I was curious what was going on in the code, so I modified it to output a log.

The code is shown here.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { DynamoDBClient, DynamoDBClientConfig, WriteRequest } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import {
    BatchWriteCommand,
    BatchWriteCommandInput,
    BatchWriteCommandOutput,
    DynamoDBDocumentClient,
} from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';
import { BatchDeleteArguments, DynamoDbConfig } from '../../../type/dynamoDbType';
export class DynamoDb {
    private readonly tableName: string;
    private readonly client: DynamoDBClient;
    private readonly documentClient: DynamoDBDocumentClient;

    constructor(config: DynamoDbConfig) {
        let connectionData: DynamoDBClientConfig = {
            region: 'ap-northeast-1',
        };

        if (config.endpoint) {
            connectionData.endpoint = config.endpoint;
        }

        this.client = new DynamoDBClient(connectionData);
        this.tableName = config.tableName;
        this.documentClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(this.client);
    }

    public async batchDelete(args: BatchDeleteArguments): Promise<void> {
        console.log('batchDelete start');
        try {
            const maxBatchSize = 25;
            const batchedKeys: { [keyName: string]: string | number }[][] = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < args.keys.length; i += maxBatchSize) {
                batchedKeys.push(args.keys.slice(i, i + maxBatchSize));
            }

            const promises = batchedKeys.map(async (batch, index) => {
                console.log(`Start of parallel processing ${index}`);
                console.log('create request');
                const deleteRequests: WriteRequest[] = batch.map((key) => {
                    return {
                        DeleteRequest: {
                            Key: key as any, // Use type assertion here
                        },
                    };
                });
                console.log('end create request');

                console.log('creat param');
                const params: BatchWriteCommandInput = {
                    RequestItems: {
                        [this.tableName]: deleteRequests,
                    },
                };
                console.log('end create param');

                console.log('create command');
                const command = new BatchWriteCommand(params);
                console.log('end create command');

                console.log(`start delete ${index}`);
                const result: BatchWriteCommandOutput = await this.documentClient.send(command);
                console.log(`end delete ${index}`);

                console.log(result);

                if (result?.UnprocessedItems && Object.keys(result.UnprocessedItems).length !== 0) {
                    const failedKeys =
                        result.UnprocessedItems[this.tableName]
                            ?.map((request) => request?.DeleteRequest?.Key as any)
                            .filter(Boolean) || [];
                    return failedKeys;
                }
                console.log(`End of parallel processing ${index}`);

                return [];
            });
            console.log('Wait of parallel processing');
            const unprocessedKeyResults = await Promise.all(promises);
            console.log('End of parallel processing');
            const unprocessedKeys = unprocessedKeyResults.flat();

            if (unprocessedKeys.length > 0) {
                throw new Error('Some items could not be deleted: ' + JSON.stringify(unprocessedKeys));
            }
        } catch (err: unknown) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output log.

```
START RequestId: xxxxxx Version: $LATEST
2023-10-16T02:58:20.190Z    xxxxxx  INFO    batchDelete start
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    Start of parallel processing 0
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    create request
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    end create request
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    creat param
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    end create param
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    create command
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    end create command
2023-10-16T02:58:20.191Z    xxxxxx  INFO    start delete 0
```

You will see that the process is stopped at `await this.documentClient.send(command);`.

The log of the second run is shown here.

```
START RequestId: xxxxxxx Version: $LATEST
2023-10-16T03:19:36.473Z    xxxxxxx INFO    end delete 0
2023-10-16T03:19:36.473Z    xxxxxxx INFO    {
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'xxxxxxxx',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  UnprocessedItems: {},
  ItemCollectionMetrics: undefined
}
2023-10-16T03:19:36.475Z    xxxxxx  INFO    End of parallel processing 0
2023-10-16T03:19:36.475Z    xxxxxx  INFO    End of parallel processing
2023-10-16T03:19:36.645Z    xxxxxx  INFO    batchDelete start
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    Start of parallel processing 0
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    create request
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    end create request
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    creat param
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    end create param
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    create command
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    end create command
2023-10-16T03:19:36.646Z    xxxxxx  INFO    start delete 0
2023-10-16T03:19:36.647Z    xxxxxx  INFO    Wait of parallel processing
END RequestId: xxxxxx
REPORT RequestId: xxxxxx    Duration: 231.87 ms Billed Duration: 232 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 132 MB
```

You can see that the continuation of the previous process is being executed.

When the second Lambda execution finishes, you can see that the record has been deleted.

Why does it behave this way?